# Saving a file in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I already could open the save file dialog, but when i run the program and tried to save it, it could, but the file is not there. WHy is that? Here is the code:

```
_saved = false;

SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialog1.Filter = "System File (*.pos) | *.pos";
saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save File As";
saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

if (_saved)
{
    this.Text = "Database - " + saveFileDialog1.FileName + "";
    _filename = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
}   
else
{
    this.Text = this.Text;
}
```

Thank you, I appreciate your help.

Comment: what exactly you want to ask

Comment: You haven't actually saved anything here.

Comment: `SaveFileDialog` **does not** save file for you. It just helps you to select the location for the file being saved. You have to look in the namespace `System.IO` to seek for classes used to save the file and handle many other IO tasks.

Comment: For an example, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx) Also, `_saved` will always be false here.

Answer (score 2):

The FileSaveDialog only gives you the UI to choose the file, once the file was choosen by the user you will get the FileName and is now your responsibility to do whatever is necesary with the FileName, such as storing your data and save it.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement the save action by yourself, here is an example.

```
if(sf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    using(var fs = new FileStream(sf.FileName,FileMode.Create))
    {
        // get bytes from text you want to save
        byte [] data =new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(text); 
        fs.Write(data,0,data.Length);
        fs.Flush();
    }
}
```

sf is **saveFileDialog1**